# Ubuntu-one - host requires authentication

Tags: ubuntu-one, 13.10

When I try to log in Ubuntu one in Saucy always say "host requires authentication". What can I do?

Comment: It's a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-control-panel/+bug/964172

Answer (score 0):

Workaround was presented in this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntuone-control-panel/+bug/964172), check page for current fix status.

- Start `seahorse`
- Delete `UbuntuOne token for https://ubuntuone.com`